# ORA-01843 Not a Valid Month with Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I'm using a sql statement in my program.

```
stringBuffer sql=new StringBuffer();
sql.append("insert into customer (id,createddate) ");
sql.append("values (1,");
sql.append("'"+new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())+"'");

String results=jdbcTemplate.update(sql.toString();
```

when i executed above command,i got this exception
 nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01843: not a valid month

i should bind the current date ,how do i solve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use String literals. Use a prepared statement and pass a Timestamp object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use the DB's date then use `sysdate` ie:

```
stringBuffer sql=new StringBuffer();
sql.append("insert into customer (id,createddate) ");
sql.append("values (1,sysdate)");
```

Or you can add a `to_date` to the query:

```
stringBuffer sql=new StringBuffer();
sql.append("insert into customer (id,createddate) ");
sql.append("values (1,to_date(");
sql.append("'"+<your TimeStamp converted to a String like yyyyMMddHHmmss>+"', 'yyyymmddhh24miss'");
```

Or use a **PreparedStatement** as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858182/preparedstatement-and-settimestamp-in-oracle-jdbc)

Comment: +1 - I was going to launch into a long diatribe about formatting dates/times, etc, blah, then had a serious "doh!" moment when I read your answer.  :-)