# PostgreSQL function returns different values with timestamp comparison on/off

Tags: postgresql, function, date

I have a little function (used to be a part of a big one, but I've isolated the segment for this question):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION weird_date_issue_function() RETURNS INT AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  deleted_count INT := 0;
BEGIN
  SELECT count(*)
  INTO deleted_count
  FROM user_verifications
  WHERE verified = FALSE AND now() - create_date > INTERVAL '1 second';
  RETURN deleted_count;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The `user_verification` indeed contains an unverified entry older than 1 second (for testing purposes).

When I call `select weird_date_issue_function();` from my IDE, it returns 1.
But when I call it using `jdbc.queryForObject("SELECT weird_date_issue_function()", Integer.class);`
it returns 0.

But wait, that's not all. If I comment out the `AND now() - create_date > INTERVAL '1 second';` part, I get 1 in my application as well. What is going on here?

Comment: `now()` returns the time at the start of the **transaction**. So if you are running with autocommit off, that might be a "long time ago". Use one of the other time functions: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT e.g. `clock_timestamp()`

Answer (score 0):

After a some searching and debugging, it seems that the timezones were the problem.

Both from my application and my IDE, the things like `select now()` would return the same, but as soon as I attempted any calculations, things went wrong.

By executing `select now() - create_date from user_verifications`, I would get the following two results (the first one being the correct one, from the IDE):

```
0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 48 mins 40.564828 secs
0 years 0 mons 0 days -1 hours -11 mins -23.698618 secs
```

Since I'm in the CEST timezone, this smelled fishy. After finding [PostgreSQL 9.2 JDBC driver uses client time zone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447995/postgresql-9-2-jdbc-driver-uses-client-time-zone), it was enough for me to add

```
<property name="connectionInitSql" value="SET TIME ZONE 'CET'"/>
```

to my spring config until I find out more information about this issue.