# Obtaining PostgreSQL Database Time Zone in Java Returns Local Machine Time Zone

Tags: java, database, postgresql, spring-boot

I have a Java function that retrieves the PostgreSQL database time zone using the query `SELECT current_setting('TIMEZONE');`. However, the returned time zone corresponds to the local machine's time zone instead of the actual time zone configured for the database.

Here are the relevant details:

- **Local Machine (Computer) Time Zone**: "Asia/Singapore"
- **Database Time Zone**: "America/Los_Angeles"

In the PostgreSQL SQL shell (psql), I can successfully obtain the database time zone using the query mentioned above:

```
target_database=# SELECT current_setting('TIMEZONE');
   current_setting
---------------------
 America/Los_Angeles
(1 row)
```

However, when executing the same query in Java using the following code snippet, it returns the local machine's time zone ("Asia/Singapore"):

```
public static String get_database_time_zone(String database_type, String host, Integer port, String database_name, String database_instance, String database_username, String database_password){
    try(
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
        connection_url(database_type, host, port, database_name, database_instance),
        database_username,
        database_password);
      Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    ){
      ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT current_setting('TIMEZONE');");

      if (res.next()) {
        System.out.println(res.getString(1)); //"Asia/Singapore"
        return res.getString(1);
      }

    } catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
  }
```

I would appreciate any insights on how to modify this code to correctly retrieve the database time zone instead of the local machine time zone. Thank you!

Comment: JDBC connection issue. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50985380/postgresql-jdbc-driver-uses-client-time-zone) SO thread might help. Or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447995/postgresql-9-2-jdbc-driver-uses-client-time-zone)