# Timestamp discrepancies between SQL server and Java

Tags: java, sql-server, t-sql, jdbc, timestamp

I need to replicate a simple procedure from Java code to SQL Server stored procedure. It will go into a SQL Azure db in production, but I'm testing it against my local SQL Express 12 install.

A part of this stored procedure is to concatenate some values into a string.

This is my example Java code:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import com.google.common.base.Strings;

public static String concat() {
  //init variables with sample data
  DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS");
  Timestamp date = new Timestamp(dateFormat.parse("04/04/2014 21:07:13.897").getTime());

  //format variables into 0-filled strings
  String formattedDate = String.format("%011d", date.getTime() / 1000);

  //concat those strings
  String finalString = ... + formattedDate + ...;
  return finalString;    
}
```

Variables:

```
| date                    | formatted_date |
| ----------------------- | -------------- |
| 2014-04-04 21:07:13.897 | 01396638433    |
```

This is the equivalent in SQL:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME;
DECLARE @formatted_date CHAR(11);
DECLARE @final_string CHAR(22);

--init variables with same data as Java code
SET @date = '2014/04/04 21:07:13.897';

--format variables into 0-filled strings
SET @formatted_date = FORMAT(DATEDIFF(s,'1970-01-01 00:00:00', @date), '00000000000');

--concat those strings
SET @final_string = CONCAT(..., @formatted_date, ...);
```

Variables:

```
| date                    | formatted_date |
| ----------------------- | -------------- |
| 2014-04-04 21:07:13.897 | 01396645633    |
```

While checking if the output was the same I noticed the dates are not the same:

```
Java output:  01396638433
MSSQL output: 01396645633
```

I opened [this site](http://www.epochconverter.com/) to see what this difference meant:

```
Java:  GMT: Fri, 04 Apr 2014 19:07:13 GMT, Your time zone: 4/4/2014 21:07:13 GMT+2
MSSQL: GMT: Fri, 04 Apr 2014 21:07:13 GMT, Your time zone: 4/4/2014 23:07:13 GMT+2
```

Exactly two hours difference.

I've found a query to run against SQL Server to check time zone settings:

```
DECLARE @TZ SMALLINT
SELECT @TZ=DATEPART(TZ, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())

DECLARE @TimeZone VARCHAR(50)
EXEC MASTER.dbo.xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation',
'TimeZoneKeyName',@TimeZone OUT

SELECT @TimeZone, CAST(@TZ/60 AS VARCHAR(5))+':'+Cast(ABS(@TZ)%60 AS VARCHAR(5));
```

Output:

```
| Time zone               | Offset  |
| ----------------------- | ------- |
| W. Europe Standard Time | 2:0     |
```

I checked JVM time zone like this:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(now.getTimeZone());
System.out.println(System.getProperties().get("user.timezone").toString());
```

Output:

```
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Berlin",offset=3600000, dstSavings=3600000,
transitions=143, lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Berlin, offset=3600000, 
dstSavings=3600000, startYear=0, startMode=2, startMonth=2, startDay=-1,
startDayOfWeek=1, startTime=3600000, startTimeMode=2, endMode=2, endMonth=9,
endDay=-1, endDayOfWeek=1, endTime=3600000, endTimeMode=2]]
Europe/Berlin
```

How can I get equal timestamps between Java and SQL Server?

Comment: Timestamps in JDBC are required to use the local timezone, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070572/is-java-sql-timestamp-timezone-specific/14070771#14070771

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though Mark Rotteveel and dean gave enlightening answers I ended up doing the following:

at the beginning of my application init method I set

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

and all SQL calls to

```
getdate()
```

have been replaced with

```
getutcdate()
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3):

On SQL Server side of things --

There is a function in SQL Server called `getutcdate()` which returns current UTC time. Comparing this with `getdate()` you can get the time difference from UTC and modify the value to format.

```
select datediff(s, getutcdate(), getdate())
```

Better than accessing registry in any case.

So, the SQL Server code should look like this:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME;
DECLARE @formatted_date CHAR(11);
DECLARE @final_string CHAR(22);
DECLARE @diff_sec int;

--init variables with same data as Java code
SET @date = '2014/04/04 21:07:13.897';

--get the difference between UTC and local in seconds
SET @diff_sec = datediff(s, getutcdate(), getdate());

--format variables into 0-filled strings
SET @formatted_date = FORMAT(DATEDIFF(s,'1970-01-01 00:00:00', @date) - @diff_sec, '00000000000');

--concat those strings
SET @final_string = CONCAT(..., @formatted_date, ...);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So you think problem lies by SQL server side? How should getutcdate() help me with my string format problem? What should I do with its 7200 output?

Answer (score 2):

JDBC requires - absent any timezone information - that timestamps are stored and retrieved using the local timezone.

This means that if your local system is Europe\Berlin, then a date stored as `2014-04-04 21:07:13.897` in the database is processed as `2014-04-04 21:07:13.897 CEST` (Central European Summer Time) and not as `2014-04-04 21:07:13.897 UTC`.

CEST offset is 2 hours ahead of UTC or 7200 seconds, which explains the difference you observe as:

```
1396645633 - 1396645633 = 7200
```

Similar when Java stores a timestamp into a database, it will send the timestamp as if it is in the current timezone. So if you try to store `2014-04-04 21:07:13.897 UTC`, then it uses `2014-04-04 23:07:13.897 CEST` and it sends to SQL Server `2014-04-04 23:07:13.897`.

Although it is not explicitly specified for `setTimestamp(int parameterIndex, Timestamp x)` drivers have to follow the rules established by the [`setTimestamp(int parameterIndex, Timestamp x, Calendar cal)` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp%28int,%20java.sql.Timestamp,%20java.util.Calendar%29):

> Sets the designated parameter to the given `java.sql.Timestamp` value, using the given `Calendar` object. The driver uses the `Calendar` object to construct an SQL `TIMESTAMP` value, which the driver then sends to the database. With a `Calendar` object, the driver can calculate the timestamp taking into account a custom timezone. **If no `Calendar` object is specified, the driver uses the default timezone, which is that of the virtual machine running the application.**

See for more details: [Is java.sql.Timestamp timezone specific?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070572/is-java-sql-timestamp-timezone-specific/14070771#14070771)

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer. What I do not have clear is how to change my Java code to make things right. I currently generate the timestamp with new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()) and then send that value to the database. At a later time there is a scheduled SQL stored procedure that reads that value and does some calculations. What can you suggest me to change?

Comment: If you want to always use a specific timezone, then use the setter (and getter) method that takes a `Calendar` object; and use a `Calendar` with the right timezone. If you use Java 8 and your driver already implemented the new `java.time` support specified in JDBC 4.2 you could also consider using the `java.time.LocalDateTime` class together with `set/getObject` (but I am not sure how many drivers already fully support this).

Comment: I would like to not have to input machine time zone, because it would lead to conversion problems in the case I move my servers to another region.. Is there a way to always save/read timestamps as UTC?

Comment: Yes: use a `Calendar` with a timezone set to UTC when setting or retrieving the timestamp, or use the `LocalDateTime` object if your driver supports that.