# Hibernate: @Temporal with different timezone on server and mysql

Tags: java, hibernate, date, utc

I got a simple question:

Having such an entity

```
@Entity
public class Entity {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date created = new Date();
}
```

If I saved one with a server having GMT+4 for TimeZone, with a UTC DB server

```
Entity entity = new Entity();
entityDao.save(entity);
```

What is really saved?
Does Hibernate convert the GMT+4 into UTC when saving?

Comment: You can use SqlDate...

Comment: The internals are explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070572/is-java-sql-timestamp-timezone-specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the easy way is to have mysql in UTC:

/etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
default-time-zone = '+00:00'
```

And set the JAVA_OPTS for the tomcat : -Duser.timezone=GMT