# Stuck with java Timestamp

Tags: java

Can somebody find what is wrong with this code. I am trying to convert the Date Time value to Long using the Date and Time Stamp.These two always returns two different values for the same date time.

```
    String date = "2016-01-08 06:23:13.0";
    if(date.lastIndexOf('.') != -1)
    {
        date = date.substring(0,date.lastIndexOf('.'));
        date = date+"+0000";
    }
    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ");
    Date myDate = fmt.parse(date);

    System.out.println(myDate); 
    long timestamp = myDate.getTime();
    System.out.println("The time stamp value is " + timestamp);

    Timestamp tm = Timestamp.valueOf("2016-01-08 06:23:13.0");
    System.out.println("The time stamp value using Timestamp is " + tm.getTime());
```

Comment: What happens if you do `tm = Timestamp.valueOf(date)`? Those manipulations in lines 2-5 are not being represented in the Timestamp processing.

Comment: Simply using `SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");` works just fine for me

Comment: The first value is been set to +0 time zone, the second is using the current time offset (in my case 9 hours)

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a time zone specification to your first variant:

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ");
                                                                ^
```

If you ommitt this, and specify the same input values for both calculations, the result is the same.

```
...
    String date = "2016-01-08 06:23:13";

    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date myDate = fmt.parse(date);
    System.out.println(myDate);

    long timestamp = myDate.getTime();
    System.out.println("The time stamp value is " + timestamp);

    Timestamp tm = Timestamp.valueOf(date);
    long t2 = tm.getTime();

    System.out.println("The time stamp value using Timestamp is " + t2 + " (diff: " + (t2 - timestamp) + ")");
...
```

```
Fri Jan 08 06:23:13 CET 2016
The time stamp value is 1452230593000
The time stamp value using Timestamp is 1452230593000 (diff: 0)
```

See @Joni's answer for an explaination:

- With your explicit timezone specification of `+0000` you specify UTC+0 as the time zone
- Timestamp, on the other hand, assumes your local time zone which leads to a different value unless you live in UTC+0. (Actually it seems a bit more subtle: see [Is java.sql.Timestamp timezone specific?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070572/is-java-sql-timestamp-timezone-specific) for more information)

Answer (score 0):

Your code with SimpleDateFormat parses the date assuming the zero digits specify the UTC timezone. Timestamp assumes local timezone.