# java.sql.Timestamp#valueOf result depends on default timezone

Tags: java, timezone, timestamp

I've made experiment

```
for (String tz: TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()) {
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(tz));
    timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf("1970-01-01 00:00:00.000");
    System.out.println(tz + " - " + timestamp.getTime());
}
```

unexpectedly result was different for each timezone. What is the logic behind this? always thought that timestamp is timezone-independant.

Comment: `"1970-01-01 00:00:00.000"` had to be interpreted in the context of _some_ timezone, so it uses the default timezone. Did you think it would just use UTC?

Comment: @GriffeyDog yep, the problem is that date string comes from DB and it is treated as UTC date

Comment: `String`s don't have a timezone. To convert from a `String` to a `Timestamp`, a timezone needs to be applied. `valueOf` uses the default timezone to make the conversion from `String` to `Timestamp`.

Comment: @GriffeyDog hmm strange that Timestamp doesn't support specifying timezone in string then

Comment: See dup link, and also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14070771/634824) for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Because Timestamp use UTC TimeZone, if you change Timezone It will be different, i.e. when in London was 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 (GMT+1) in spanish Canary Islands was 1969-12-31 23:00:00.000 (GMT)

*EDIT: For most purposes, UTC is considered interchangeable with GMT

Comment: Actually, at 1970-01-01, London was at GMT+1, and Canary Islands were at GMT.  Your times are correct, but your offsets are both off by an hour.

Comment: @MattJohnson Thanks for aclaration!