# Do Timestamp operations work on UNIX_TIMESTAMP or Visual Representation of Timestamp

Tags: datetime, calendar, timestamp, mariadb, jodatime

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14070771/2701126) and As per MySQL documentation for Timestamp:

> It can hold values starting at '1970-01-01 00:00:01' (UTC) to
>   '2038-01-19 05:14:07' (UTC) . This range is caused by MariaDB storing
>   the TIMESTAMP values as the number of seconds since '1970-01-01
>   00:00:00' (UTC).

so all the timestamp related operations are done in UNIX_TIMESTAMP as there is no timezone info stored in timestamp. That was my understanding.

My current time zone: IST (+05:30)
After midnight, when **date changed in IST but not in UTC** I did an insert operation. I thought if I do a DATE(now()) for IST it should show the yesterday's stored record as I thought UNIX_TIMESTAMP will be used for timestamp comparison which will remain same.

In below code block you can see the timezone offset as +05:30 which is for IST. Record against ID = 5 was inserted at 13th Feb,2017 00:04 pm. But in UTC_STAMP would have been somewhere 12th Feb,2017 18hr34min(5hr30min back). So date is not changed in UTC. I did a select statement for date = 13th Feb 2017, I thought I would I get (1,2,3,5) records as result because UTC representation of 13th Feb 2017,00:00 in IST still falls under UTC date of 12thFeb,2017 . But I got only record against ID = 5.

Q.1
In short I was thinking that **value = 2017-02-13** will be converted to UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a numerical value) and then comparison occurs. What I am missing ? or else mention the steps taken by db to generate the below result ? I hope I was able explain myself.

Q.2 How does java.sql.Timestamp executes ? It works something like mentioned in code block or it first converts timestamp values to unix_timestamp and then do the conversion or is it database internal implementation compares long values of timestamp ?

```
MariaDB [test]>SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;

+--------------------+---------------------+
| @@global.time_zone | @@session.time_zone |
+--------------------+---------------------+
| SYSTEM             | +05:30              |
+--------------------+---------------------+

MariaDB [test]> desc t;
+-------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------   -------------+
| Field | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                              |
+-------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id    | int(11)   | YES  |     | NULL              |                                    |
| ts    | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+---------------    --------------+

MariaDB [test]> select * from t;
+------+---------------------+
| id   | ts                  |
+------+---------------------+
|    1 | 2017-02-12 22:10:35 |
|    2 | 2017-02-12 22:10:35 |
|    3 | 2017-02-12 22:13:06 |
|    4 | 2001-07-22 12:12:12 |
|    5 | 2017-02-13 00:04:01 |
+------+---------------------+

MariaDB [test]> select * from t where date(ts) = '2017-02-13';
+------+---------------------+
| id   | ts                  |
+------+---------------------+
|    5 | 2017-02-13 00:04:01 |
+------+---------------------+

MariaDB [test]> set time_zone = '+00:00';

MariaDB [test]> SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
+--------------------+---------------------+
| @@global.time_zone | @@session.time_zone |
+--------------------+---------------------+
| SYSTEM             | +00:00              |
+--------------------+---------------------+

MariaDB [test]> select * from t;
+------+---------------------+
| id   | ts                  |
+------+---------------------+
|    1 | 2017-02-12 16:40:35 |
|    2 | 2017-02-12 16:40:35 |
|    3 | 2017-02-12 16:43:06 |
|    4 | 2001-07-22 06:42:12 |
|    5 | 2017-02-12 18:34:01 |
+------+---------------------+

MariaDB [test]> select * from t where date(ts) = '2017-02-12';
+------+---------------------+
| id   | ts                  |
+------+---------------------+
|    1 | 2017-02-12 16:40:35 |
|    2 | 2017-02-12 16:40:35 |
|    3 | 2017-02-12 16:43:06 |
|    5 | 2017-02-12 18:34:01 |
+------+---------------------+
```

EDIT1:  I tried using database server with UTC timezone and IST as application server. After midnight, when IST changed its date and UTC didn't- I repeated the insert and create operations as mentioned above.Below are the records and info:

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
+--------------------+---------------------+
| @@global.time_zone | @@session.time_zone |
+--------------------+---------------------+
| UTC                | UTC                 |
+--------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.30 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select * from t ;
+----+---------------------+
| id | ts                  |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2017-02-13 19:22:15 |
|  2 | 2017-02-13 19:22:15 |
|  3 | 2017-02-13 19:21:40 |
|  4 | 2001-07-22 12:12:12 |
|  5 | 2017-02-14 00:56:13 |
+----+---------------------+
5 rows in set (0.40 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select UTC_TIMESTAMP;
+---------------------+
| UTC_TIMESTAMP       |
+---------------------+
| 2017-02-13 19:21:22 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.38 sec)
```

And used JDBC, to get the response:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE date(ts) = date(:currentDate);

where, currentDate = Timestamp.from(Instant.now()); from Java
```

Response was:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "timestamp1": 1486993935000
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "timestamp1": 1486993935000
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "timestamp1": 1486993900000
    }
]
```

why record(id=5) did not came ? Doesn't it mean that it looks for Visual Representation rather than extract date from UTC_TIMESTAMP numerical value if it would have done that it would have fetched record with id = 5.

Comment: Please convert your screenshots to pure text (code block). There is really no need to post terminal output as a screenshot.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel my bad. I thought snapshot would be better. Anyways, I have made the changes as per you comment.

Comment: What timezone does _Java_ think it is?

Comment: @RickJames IST only.