# How do I set JDBC's timezone on a query basis?

Tags: java, jdbc, timezone

One way to do this is the following.

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("yourTimeZone"));
```

However, it will affect the entire JVM. Is there a way to do it on a query basis that is safe and will not have impact to the rest of the application or JVM that may have assumed a specific timezone?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070572/is-java-sql-timestamp-timezone-specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the time zone you want when setting/getting `Timestamp` values.

> [`PreparedStatement.setTimestamp(int parameterIndex, Timestamp x, Calendar cal)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp-int-java.sql.Timestamp-java.util.Calendar-)
>
> With a Calendar object, the driver can calculate the timestamp taking into account a custom timezone. If no Calendar object is specified, the driver uses the default timezone, which is that of the virtual machine running the application.

> [`ResultSet.getTimestamp(String columnLabel, Calendar cal)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp-java.lang.String-java.util.Calendar-)
>
> This method uses the given calendar to construct an appropriate millisecond value for the timestamp if the underlying database does not store timezone information.

Both use the time zone of the calendar:

> [`Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone zone)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance-java.util.TimeZone-)
>
> Gets a calendar using the specified time zone and default locale.

> [`Calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTimeZone-java.util.TimeZone-)
>
> Sets the time zone with the given time zone value.

Comment: Note that the `Calendar` object is only used for the timezone information (or at least, that is the intention of the JDBC requirements).