# MySQL select datetime without Daylight saving time change

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a table where I store data from the sensors

```
CREATE TABLE `testdatabase` (
  `dateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sensorID` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6918 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

This is the select query I am running,

```
SELECT `dateTime` from testdatabase WHERE sensorID='ABC1234' AND (dateTime BETWEEN '2017-03-26 00:01:00' AND '2017-03-26 00:00:00') order by `dateTime` asc;
```

In MySQL workbench when I run this query, it returns the correct date time.

```
2017-03-26 00:10:00
2017-03-26 00:20:00
2017-03-26 00:30:00
2017-03-26 00:40:00
2017-03-26 00:50:00
2017-03-26 01:00:00
2017-03-26 01:10:00
2017-03-26 01:20:00
2017-03-26 01:30:00
2017-03-26 01:40:00
2017-03-26 01:50:00
2017-03-26 02:00:00
2017-03-26 02:10:00
2017-03-26 02:20:00
2017-03-26 02:30:00
2017-03-26 02:40:00
2017-03-26 02:50:00
2017-03-26 03:00:00
```

But when I run this query from my java app, it returns the following date time.

```
2017-03-26 00:10:00
2017-03-26 00:20:00
2017-03-26 00:30:00
2017-03-26 00:40:00
2017-03-26 00:50:00
2017-03-26 02:00:00
2017-03-26 02:10:00
2017-03-26 02:20:00
2017-03-26 02:30:00
2017-03-26 02:40:00
2017-03-26 02:50:00
2017-03-26 02:00:00
2017-03-26 02:10:00
2017-03-26 02:20:00
2017-03-26 02:30:00
2017-03-26 02:40:00
2017-03-26 02:50:00
2017-03-26 03:00:00
```

Obviously this has something to do with the DST change in the UK which happened on 26th March at 1am. 
I think JDBC connection is changing the time to BST but I don't want that.

I have tried to set the MySQL server global time zone to 00:00

```
SET @@global.time_zone='+00:00';
```

But no success! 
How can I get the correct time without the DST change?

EDIT: 
I am using `Java 1.7` and `mysql-connector-java-5.1.19-bin.jar`

I was getting data as strings before but after `Mark Rotteveel` comments I tried `PreparedStaement` with the calendar object set to UTC but both returning the same results.

```
try 
{
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
    while(resultSet.next())
    {
        System.out.println("Without Calendar Object : "+resultSet.getString(1));
    }
}catch (SQLException e){e.printStackTrace();}

try
{
    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    while(resultSet.next())
    {
        System.out.println("With Calendar Object : "+resultSet.getTimestamp(1, cal));
    }
}catch (SQLException e){e.printStackTrace();}

OUTPUT:
    Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 00:10:00.0
    Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 00:20:00.0
    Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 00:30:00.0
    Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 00:40:00.0
    Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 00:50:00.0
    Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 02:00:00.0
    Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 02:10:00.0
    Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 02:20:00.0
    Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 02:30:00.0
    Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 02:40:00.0
    Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 02:50:00.0
    Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 02:00:00.0
    Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 02:10:00.0
    Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 02:20:00.0
    Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 02:30:00.0
    Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 02:40:00.0
    Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 02:50:00.0
    Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 03:00:00.0
    With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 00:10:00.0
    With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 00:20:00.0
    With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 00:30:00.0
    With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 00:40:00.0
    With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 00:50:00.0
    With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 02:00:00.0
    With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 02:10:00.0
    With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 02:20:00.0
    With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 02:30:00.0
    With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 02:40:00.0
    With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 02:50:00.0
    With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 02:00:00.0
    With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 02:10:00.0
    With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 02:20:00.0
    With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 02:30:00.0
    With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 02:40:00.0
    With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 02:50:00.0
    With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 03:00:00.0
```

**EDIT 2:**
There is another strange thing that when I change the default timezone to UTC it returns repeating values for 1am instead of 2am.

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

OUTPUT:

```
Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 00:10:00.0
Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 00:20:00.0
Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 00:30:00.0
Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 00:40:00.0
Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 00:50:00.0
Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 01:00:00.0
Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 01:10:00.0
Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 01:20:00.0
Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 01:30:00.0
Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 01:40:00.0
Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 01:50:00.0
Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 01:00:00.0
Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 01:10:00.0
Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 01:20:00.0
Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 01:30:00.0
Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 01:40:00.0
Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 01:50:00.0
Without Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 02:00:00.0
With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 00:10:00.0
With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 00:20:00.0
With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 00:30:00.0
With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 00:40:00.0
With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 00:50:00.0
With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 01:00:00.0
With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 01:10:00.0
With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 01:20:00.0
With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 01:30:00.0
With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 01:40:00.0
With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 01:50:00.0
With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 01:00:00.0
With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 01:10:00.0
With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 01:20:00.0
With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 01:30:00.0
With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 01:40:00.0
With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 01:50:00.0
With Calendar Object : 2017-03-26 02:00:00.0
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070572/is-java-sql-timestamp-timezone-specific/14070771#14070771

Comment: @MarkRotteveel In this question the data type is timestamp but my table has a datatype of datetime, I was under the impression that only timestamp stores the timezone value and datetime does not store this information

Comment: Don't confuse JDBC data types with MySQL data types. A `Types.TIMESTAMP` (or `java.sql.Timestamp`) has no time zone, but when retrieving a value from the database for a datatype that has no time zone information (like MySQLs `datetime`), then JDBC requires that it is interpreted in the current JVM timezone, unless you use the `getTimestamp` that takes a `Calendar` object with time zone information.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate the version of Java you are running and the version of the MySQL JDBC connector that you are using.

Comment: Please share the Java code you use for producing the output.

Comment: Try adding `useLegacyDatetimeCode=false` to your connection string and see if that helps.

Comment: @GordThompson still same result, I have also tried serverTimezone=UTC in the connection string, no change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues at play here:

1. Are we getting the desired `java.sql.Timestamp` values back from the server?
2. What are we actually seeing when we ask Java to display the `Timestamp` value as a date/time string?

To help sort this out we can display the `Timestamp` value in its numeric form. `Timestamp#getTime()` returns the number of milliseconds since the epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC), but we can make it a bit easier to read if we divide that by 60000 to give the minutes since the epoch.

We can also use `SimpleDateFormat` objects to format the `Timestamp` values in an unambiguous way.

So for a sample table named `tztest` that looks like this in phpMyAdmin

```
id  dateTime
--  -------------------
 1  2017-03-26 00:10:00
 2  2017-03-26 01:10:00
 3  2017-03-26 02:10:00
```

when I ran the following Java code

```java
connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/mydb";
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, myUid, myPwd)) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdfLocal = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
    Calendar calUTC = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    SimpleDateFormat sdfUTC = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
    sdfUTC.setCalendar(calUTC);
    String sql = 
            "SELECT id, CAST(dateTime AS CHAR) AS datetimeString, dateTime " + 
            "FROM tztest ORDER BY dateTime";
    try (   Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql)) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            String datetimeString = rs.getString("datetimeString");
            Timestamp timestampValue = rs.getTimestamp("dateTime", calUTC);
            long minutesSinceEpoch = timestampValue.getTime() / 60000;
            System.out.printf("%d: %s -> %d minutes since epoch -> %s / %s%n",
                    id,
                    datetimeString, 
                    minutesSinceEpoch,
                    sdfLocal.format(timestampValue),
                    sdfUTC.format(timestampValue)
                    );
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

the console output was

```
1: 2017-03-26 00:10:00 -> 24841450 minutes since epoch -> 2017-03-26 00:10:00 GMT / 2017-03-26 00:10:00 UTC
2: 2017-03-26 01:10:00 -> 24841510 minutes since epoch -> 2017-03-26 02:10:00 BST / 2017-03-26 01:10:00 UTC
3: 2017-03-26 02:10:00 -> 24841510 minutes since epoch -> 2017-03-26 02:10:00 BST / 2017-03-26 01:10:00 UTC
```

Clearly I wasn't getting the desired `Timestamp` values back since both rows 2 and 3 show "24841510 minutes since epoch".

I was able to correct that by simply adding `useLegacyDatetimeCode=false` to my connection string

```java
connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/mydb?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false";
```

after which the console output was

```
1: 2017-03-26 00:10:00 -> 24841450 minutes since epoch -> 2017-03-26 00:10:00 GMT / 2017-03-26 00:10:00 UTC
2: 2017-03-26 01:10:00 -> 24841510 minutes since epoch -> 2017-03-26 02:10:00 BST / 2017-03-26 01:10:00 UTC
3: 2017-03-26 02:10:00 -> 24841570 minutes since epoch -> 2017-03-26 03:10:00 BST / 2017-03-26 02:10:00 UTC
```

Notice that row 3 now shows "24841570 minutes since epoch", 60 minutes later than row 2. Notice also that the UTC-formatted datetime value matches the string representation we got by using `CAST(dateTime AS CHAR)` in the SQL query.

Comment: Thanks Gord... adding `useLegacyDatetimeCode=false` in the connection string solved the issue and your example helped. I have one more question, Does java treat both (`timestamp` and `datetime`) MySQL data types as timestamp? Because in my database table, the data type is datetime but when I get the data in ResultSet object, its class is timestamp (`resultSet.getObject(1).getClass().getName() = java.sql.timestamp`)

Comment: By default, MySQL Connector/J will return values from both `DATETIME` columns and `TIMESTAMP` columns as `java.sql.Timestamp` objects. However, it does not change the behaviour of those column types in the MySQL database. The fact that MySQL `TIMESTAMP` columns and `java.sql.Timestamp` objects share the same "timestamp" name is really just coincidence.