# MySQL client vs server time zone

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, jdbc, timezone

I'm running into an issue where MySQL stores different date time values than the client passes. The server runs in UTC and the client in a different time zone. Somehow MySQL seems to convert date time values between the client and server time zone even though the SQL types `DATE`, `TIME` and `TIMESTAMP` all have no time zone. No other database I tested so far has this behaviour.

The following code can be used to reproduce the issue. When the server runs in UTC the code only works when the client also runs in UTC.

```
try (Connection connection = this.dataSource.getConnection();
     PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
             "SELECT ? = DATE '1988-12-25', ? = TIME '15:09:02', ? = TIMESTAMP '1980-01-01 23:03:20'")) {
  preparedStatement.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf("1988-12-25"));
  preparedStatement.setTime(2, java.sql.Time.valueOf("15:09:02"));
  preparedStatement.setTimestamp(3, java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("1980-01-01 23:03:20"));
  try (ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
    while (resultSet.next()) {
      System.out.println(resultSet.getBoolean(1));
      System.out.println(resultSet.getBoolean(2));
      System.out.println(resultSet.getBoolean(3));
    }
  }

}
```

I'm using

- MySQL 5.7.14
- mysql-connector-java 6.0.5
- Oracle Java 1.8.0_131

My JDBC URL is just `jdbc:mysql://host:port/database`

**edit**

My reasoning why time zones should not play a role here and no time zone conversion should happen is two fold. Firstly on the SQL level `TIMESTAMP` is an alias for `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` which strongly implies that unlike `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` it values have no time zone. In other words values are not instants in time but rather in local date time values.

Secondly that `java.sql.Timestamp` is in JVM time zone is merely artefact of being a subclass of `java.util.Date`. (I am aware that `java.util.Date` has no time zone). The Javadoc of `java.sql.Timestamp` of makes it quite clear that relationship is only for implementation purposes.

I feel both of these assertions are confirmed by the fact that in Java SE 8 / JDBC 4.2 `java.sql.Timestamp` is mapped to `java.time.LocalDateTime` and not `java.time.ZonedDateTime` or `java.time.OffsetDateTime`.

**edit 2**

I do not understand why `TIMESTAMP` values are subject to time zone conversion. Unlike `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZOONE` These are "local" values and do not have an associated time zone and should therefore have no time zone conversion applied to them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070572/is-java-sql-timestamp-timezone-specific

Comment: The MySQL Connector/J (JDBC driver) handling of timezone difference (server UTC, client not UTC) seems to be a bizarre mishmash of unpredictable behavior. There are several interrelated configuration properties that influence behavior of the JDBC driver handling of timezone conversions for datetime and timestamp, e.g.  useLegacyDatetimeCode, useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift, noTimezoneConversionForDateType, treatUtilDateAsTimestamp, et al. We had to experiment to find a combination of connection properties that resulted in a behavior we could predict and accommodate.

Comment: @spencer7593 I can't find any of the in the [current documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/6.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) most of them seem to have been [removed in 6.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/6.0/en/connector-j-properties-changed.html)

Comment: This might better be posted on StackStatusReport, since there doesn't appear to be any question being asked here.

Comment: The question is why does this code not work and how do I get it to work.

Comment: You could try the [overload](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate(int,%20java.sql.Date,%20java.util.Calendar)) that takes a `Calendar` for specifying a time zone.

Comment: The reported behavior is consistent with the behavior we expect. There's a *literal* in the text of the SQL statement, and a *bind value*. The bind value is subject to timezone conversion (datetime handling) in Connector/J. The literal passes as part of the static SQL text, unaffected. If we need a comparison of the two values to evaluate as equal, then we  need to *disable* the timezone conversion on the bind value. If we set the client timezone the same as the server timezone, no timezone conversion occurs (as already observed). Otherwise, we would need to disable the timezone conversion.

Comment: ... (cont.) or get around it somehow. To get the code to return the (odd) result, we could pass the bind value as a different datatype (e.g. a string) so its not subject to TZ conversion. Or we can influence the behavior of Connector/J in regards to timezone conversion for Date, Datetime, Timestamp datatypes. That's where the comment about the Connector/J properties comes in... influencing the behavior. With the new 6.0 version, it appears MySQL may have abandoned a confusingly odd variety of behavior in favor of just doing the right thing. Or maybe just undocumented the properties.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with the comment that timezone handling under MySQL JDBC can be confusing, but in this case ...

> MySQL stores different date time values than the client passes

... is not quite correct. It interprets and/or displays the *string representation* of the same datetime value *in the context of the server timezone*.

First you need to understand that `java.sql.Timestamp#valueOf` creates a Timestamp value in the local timezone under which the Java Virtual Machine is running. So, for my machine which is on "Mountain Time" in Canada (UTC-7 for Standard Time):

```java
System.out.printf("Local (client) timezone is %s%n", TimeZone.getDefault().getID());

java.sql.Timestamp tStamp = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("1980-01-01 23:03:20");

SimpleDateFormat sdfLocal = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
SimpleDateFormat sdfUTC = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
sdfUTC.setCalendar(Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")));

System.out.println("tStamp = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(\"1980-01-01 23:03:20\")");
System.out.printf("                        ... which is %s%n", sdfLocal.format(tStamp));
System.out.printf("                        ... which is %s%n", sdfUTC.format(tStamp));
```

prints

```
Local (client) timezone is America/Edmonton
tStamp = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf("1980-01-01 23:03:20")
                        ... which is 1980-01-01 23:03:20 MST
                        ... which is 1980-01-02 06:03:20 UTC
```

Now, when we pass that Timestamp value to a PreparedStatement and send it off to a MySQL server that is using the UTC timezone, the server interprets and displays string literal representations of that MySQL TIMESTAMP as UTC:

```java
String connUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb";
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connUrl, myUid, myPwd)) {
    String sql = "SELECT CAST((TIMESTAMP ?) AS CHAR) AS foo";
    try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        ps.setTimestamp(1, tStamp);
        try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
            rs.next();
            System.out.printf("String representation of TIMESTAMP value at server: %s%n", 
                    rs.getString(1));
        }
    }
}
```

producing

```
String representation of TIMESTAMP value at server: 1980-01-02 06:03:20
```

If the MySQL server had been running under Toronto time (UTC-5 for Standard Time) the output would have been ...

```
String representation of TIMESTAMP value at server: 1980-01-02 01:03:20
```

... not because the MySQL TIMESTAMP value is different, but because the *string representation* of that value *in the context of the MySQL server timezone* is different.

Comment: The "issue" that OP observes is that the code is passing both a *literal* value (as part of the SQL text), and a *bind* value. The bind value is subjected to timezone conversion (datetime handling) in Connector/J, while the literal just passes through (unaffected) as part of the SQL text. The server is interpreting the literal in the context of the server timezone. The behavior observed by OP is *expected*. (Likely OP will later encounter *unexpected* behavior with timezone conversion, and that's when all those confusing Connector/J properties will become important.) +10.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is like Gord Thompson and spencer7593 stated, that the timezone of the server and that of the connection-string of the client differ and a conversion between timezones has to be made.

I also learned something while reading your edits, as in that the java.sql.Timestamp contains no timezone.

As spencer7593 stated: "The server is interpreting the literal in the context of the server timezone".

My two approaches here would be:

1. Connect to server (UTC) with your timezone in the connection-string(e.g. &serverTimezone=Europe/Zurich).
2. Alternatively pass an instance of an Calendar with your local timezone (Calendar.getInstance()) to [PreparedStatement.setTimestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp(int,%20java.sql.Timestamp,%20java.util.Calendar)).