# Saving time data (with Zone) in Oracle DB not working because of Java SimpleDateFormat issue

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, simpledateformat

I have a field that is defined as `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

The value to be saved starts off as: `"09-23-2019 10:03:11 pm"` in the zone of  `US/Hawaii`.

This is what I am trying to save to the DB (all of the date information plus the Zone)

The database stores time information in UTC format.

As of now, the date is being stored in the DB so that it looks like this:

```
DAYS
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
23-SEP-19 10.03.11.000000 PM -05:00
23-SEP-19 10.03.11.000000 PM -05:00
```

During the processing, it runs through this code:

```
    dateStr: the date (as seen above)
    ZoneLoc: 'US/Hawaii'

    public Calendar convDateStrWithZoneTOCalendar(String dateStr,
            String ZoneLoc) throws Exception {

        // convert the string sent in from user (which uses AM/PM) to one that uses military time (24HR)
        // it
        String formattedDate = null;
        DateFormat readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(this.getPattern());
        DateFormat writeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
        writeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneLoc));
        Date date = null;
        date = readFormat.parse(dateStr);
        formattedDate = writeFormat.format(date);

        // see if you can parse the date needed WITH the TimeZone
        Date d;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneLoc));
        d = sdf.parse(formattedDate);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(d);

        system.out.println(" ZONELOC VALUE " + ZoneLoc);
        system.out.println(" RETURNED VALUE " + cal );

        return cal;
    }
```

The calendar info that is returned is:

> ZONELOC VALUE IS US/Hawaii
>
> RETURNED VALUE IS
>   java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1577678591000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Chicago",offset=-21600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=235,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/Chicago,offset=-21600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2019,MONTH=11,WEEK_OF_YEAR=1,WEEK_OF_MONTH=5,DAY_OF_MONTH=29,DAY_OF_YEAR=363,DAY_OF_WEEK=1,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=5,AM_PM=1,HOUR=10,HOUR_OF_DAY=22,MINUTE=3,SECOND=11,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=-21600000,DST_OFFSET=0]

It looks as though US/Hawaii is not being set in the RETURNED VALUE.

What can I do to be sure that this gets set?

After that, I can place it in the DB and see if the setting will "stick" and not revert back to `America/Chicago`

**Update**
@Patrick H - thanks for the input. I made the change with the pattern you specified and was able to save the data. It now looks like this:

> 2017-08-02 13:38:49 TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [26] as [TIMESTAMP] - [java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1569294191000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Chicago",offset=-21600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=235,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/Chicago,offset=-21600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2019,MONTH=8,WEEK_OF_YEAR=39,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=23,DAY_OF_YEAR=266,DAY_OF_WEEK=2,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,AM_PM=1,HOUR=10,HOUR_OF_DAY=22,MINUTE=3,SECOND=11,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=-21600000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]]

**The data in the DB looks like this:**

```
23-SEP-19 10.03.11.000000 PM -05:00
```

The Zone is still `America/Chicago` even through `US/Hawaii` was specified. How can one get `US/Hawaii` to stick and not revert back to `America/Chicago`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this output:

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1569294191000,...
```

The time value above (which means 1569294191000 milliseconds since unix epoch (`1970-01-01T00:00Z`)) is equivalent to `09-23-2019 10:03 PM` in **Chicago**. That's because `readFormat` is using the system's default timezone (which is probably `America/Chicago`, just check the value of `TimeZone.getDefault()`).

To parse the input `09-23-2019 10:03:11 pm` and consider it as the local time in Hawaii, you just need to set the corresponding timezone to the `SimpleDateFormat` instance (in this case, to `readFormat`, as it needs to know in what timezone the input date is - as you didn't set any, it uses the system's default). You also don't need the other formatters (`writeFormat` and `sdf`), only one formatter can be used to get the corresponding date:

```
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
// the input is in Hawaii timezone
parser.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Hawaii"));
Date date = parser.parse("09-23-2019 10:03:11 pm");
```

The `date` above will be equivalent to 10:03 PM in Hawaii. *Actually, the date itself contains just the milliseconds from the unix epoch (`date.getTime()` returns 1569312191000) and [has no format nor any timezone information](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/)*.

You can then set it to a `Calendar` instance (don't forget to set the calendar's timezone):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Hawaii"));
cal.setTime(date);
```

It's been some time since I used oracle's timestamp with timezone type, but I think that'll be [enough to save the correct values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14070771/7605325). The value of calendar is:

> java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1569312191000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id=**"US/Hawaii"**,offset=-36000000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=7,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2019,MONTH=8,WEEK_OF_YEAR=39,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=23,DAY_OF_YEAR=266,DAY_OF_WEEK=2,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,**AM_PM=1,HOUR=10,HOUR_OF_DAY=22,MINUTE=3,SECOND=11**,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=-36000000,DST_OFFSET=0]

---

## Java new Date/Time API

The old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api), and they're being replaced by the new APIs.

*One of the main problems is how hard and confusing it is to work with different timezones.*

If you're using **Java 8**, consider using the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api).

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, there's the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

To parse the input `09-23-2019 10:03:11 pm` you can use a `DateTimeFormatter` and parse it to a `LocalDateTime` - the input has no timezone information, so we consider only the date and time, and then we can convert it to a timezone.

```
// parse the input
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // parse AM/PM and am/pm
    .parseCaseInsensitive()
    // input pattern
    .appendPattern("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss a")
    // use English locale for am/pm symbols
    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse("09-23-2019 10:03:11 pm", fmt);
// convert to Hawaii timezone
ZonedDateTime hawaiiDate = dt.atZone(ZoneId.of("US/Hawaii"));
```

The most recent JDBC drivers have support to the new API (but only for Java 8, I guess), but if you still need to work with `Calendar`, you can easily convert a `ZonedDateTime` to it:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Hawaii"));
calendar.setTimeInMillis(hawaiiDate.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
```

In Java 8, you can also do:

```
Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.from(hawaiiDate);
```

If you need interoperability with the old `Calendar` and `Date` API's, you can use the new API internally to do the calculations and convert from/to the API's when needed.

Comment: Hey @Hugo - thanks for the detailed response! I made the changes you suggested. For the second entry referring to Calendar, instead of using "US/Hawaii", I changed it to "UTC". In my case, the DB is set to work with UTC. I'm also using Spring Boot - so - I added TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")) to the main function of the Spring Boot application. Because of this, the data can be displayed to the client based upon their location. The data is showing the correct values now. Thanks again for the input!

Answer (score 1):

According to [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), I think your formatting string is wrong. You can also see in the returned value that the month, and day are wrong. `MONTH=11,DAY_OF_MONTH=29`

This is what you currently have:
`23-SEP-19 10.03.11.000000 PM -05:00`

I think the formatting string should be: `'dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS a Z'`

It also looks like the timezone issue could be because there is a colon inside it. The documentation for SimpleDateFormat indicates it needs to be in this format instead for a RFC 822 time zone: `-0500` You may find it easier to use the General time zone component instead.

Comment: thanks for the response. I made an update to my post. Can you look? Just wondering how one get the Zone to be specified. TIA

Comment: Try and change the line that says `d = sdf.parse(formattedDate);` 
to 
`d = sdf.format(sdf.parse(formattedDate));`

Comment: I got: Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Date

Comment: From the little bit of googling I just did, it seems in order to convert it, you have to use a second SimpleDateFormat object and invoke the format command again.

Comment: You could try and change the ZoneLoc variable to be `'HST'`. I don't know if `'US/Hawaii'` is recognizable.

Comment: Now after looking at it again, the calendar is just taking in a date field. I think what you want to do is change the calendar's timezone itself. Formatting the date into a string before putting it in shouldn't matter. Try adding this line after you set the time on the calendar.

`cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneLoc));`

Comment: Well, now I have : 23-SEP-19 05.03.11.000000 PM -05:00 in the database. I think I will do some research to see which other way this will go Thanks for all of the input.