# Changing default timezone converts time in Oracle table when loading using spark.jdbc

Tags: oracle, scala, apache-spark, jdbc, timestamp

I am using Spark 2.1.0, Scala 2.11.8 and Oracle 12c, while loading spark dataframe to Oracle it converts time, Timezone on server is EDT, I am changing it to Asia/Kolkata as date in 1st record is not valid in EDT(DST kicked in at that particular hour). Below is default timezone code and dataframe

```
import java.util.TimeZone
val tz= TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata")
TimeZone.setDefault(tz)

//Create a DataFrame to Load Data
df3.show
+---+----------+--------------------+
| id| something|              dateee|
+---+----------+--------------------+
|  1|Date ---- |2017-03-12 02:02:...|
|  2|Date ---- |2017-02-12 02:02:...|
|  3|Date ---- |2017-01-12 02:02:...|
|  4|Date ---- |2017-08-01 11:21:...|
+---+----------+--------------------+
```

when I run `df3.write.mode("append").jdbc(Url, "test_timestamp", dbProp)`

Data Loaded into DB is

```
1   Date ----   3/11/2017 3:32:00 PM
2   Date ----   2/11/2017 3:32:00 PM
3   Date ----   1/11/2017 3:32:00 PM
4   Date ----   8/1/2017 1:51:33 AM
```

Table Schema -

```
Name                                      Null?    Type                        
----------------------------------------- -------- ------------------------
id                                                 NUMBER(38)                  
something                                          VARCHAR2(100)               
dateee                                             DATE
```

I want timestamp to be loaded as it is in DataFrame.
This doesn't happen when I don't use `java.util.TimeZone` and set another TimeZone as Default.

Comment: `DATE` data type does not support any time zone information. If you enter a date/time with time zone then Oracle will simply truncate the time zone information.

Comment: What do you mean by "Timezone on server is EDT". Do you mean the database operating system time zone or `DBTIMEZONE`? What is "EDT"? Check by `SELECT TZNAME, TZABBREV, TZ_OFFSET(TZNAME) FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES WHERE TZABBREV = 'EDT';`

Comment: I know DATE data type does not support any timezone, that is why this is complicated. I am running my jar by spark-submit, spark is configured on unix box which have timezone of EDT(US/Eastern with DST on). DB Timezone is set to UTC.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070572/is-java-sql-timestamp-timezone-specific