# How to store Timestamp in MS SQL Server with JPA?

Tags: java, sql-server, datetime, jpa, sql-server-2012

I have an application that works with JPA and stores date and time using UTC.
I am adding support for MS SQL Server and not sure how to store time. The standard `datetime`/`datetime2` returns data in local timezone only and not UTC.

I considered using `datetimeoffset` SQL Server data type, but instead of the standart `java.sql.Timestamp` it returns a proprietary object, incompatible with other databases I am working with.

The only semi-working solution that I found is to force JVM timezone to be UTC (e.g. `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))`). It causes MS SQL Server driver to return time in UTC for the `datetime`/`datetime2` data type.

Is there a better a solution?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070572/is-java-sql-timestamp-timezone-specific

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I am using  JPA AttributeConverter<Instant, Timestamp>, so, unfortunately, this answer does not help. I saw that there is a Calendar object inside java.sql.Timestamp, but it is inaccessible without resorting to reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to get UTC time from `datetime`/`datetime2` MS SQL Server data type which also does not break other databases.

The solution is to convert `java.sql.Timestamp` read from DB to Instant using the following code: `sqlTimestamp.toLocalDateTime().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)`

See https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/339 for a more in-depth explanation.