# setTimestamp with UTC dateTime java using CallableStatement

Tags: java, jdbc, timestamp, callable-statement

I need to set Date and Time using CallableStatement with Timezone as UTC. used the below code. But its not working.

```
CallableStatement cs = null;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
cs = localConnection.prepareCall("{CALL updateLocation(?,?,?)}");
while (ResultSet.next()) {
   try {
      cs.setLong(1, remoteResultSet.getLong("id"));
      cs.setString(2, remoteResultSet.getString("place"));
      if (ResultSet.getTimestamp("dateTme") != null) {
         String date = sdf.format(remoteResultSet.getTimestamp("dateTime"));
         Date date1 = sdf.parse(date);
         cs.setTimestamp(3, new Timestamp(date1.getTime()));
         cs.executeUpadte();
      }
   }
```

on setTimestamp with callableStatement date and Time is converted back to default Timezone. set the below paramters in jdbc url. does not work.

```
 useTimezone=true
 useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
 serverTimezone=UTC
```

Comment: You are formatting your date into a string and parsing it back into a `Date` again. Isn’t that completely pointless?

Comment: I just included my possiblities that I have tried so as to store UTC dateTime.

Comment: Which database and driver? And see also [Is java.sql.Timestamp timezone specific?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070572/is-java-sql-timestamp-timezone-specific)

Comment: fetching from MSSQL and storing in MYSQL databse. using type 4  driver

Comment: Edited the reply. please check. Followed the mentioned link. doesnt work

Comment: What doesn't work, did you try the suggested method with passing a `Calendar` object?

Comment: yes I did. Its getting converted to UTC datetime. But setTimestamp is internally converting to default timezone and overriding the value.