# Updating table with timestamp attempting to convert to UTC again?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm working on an appointment scheduler for a client and I'm getting very frustrated with an error I'm encountering regarding constantly having to deal with reformatting dates between utc, strings (containing start times, ex 8:00AM to a local time, then to localdatetime etc).

I've managed to isolate it to a single method call but I cannot find how in the world my sql update is being ruined.

My table entry before the call to 'update'

```
 appointmentId, customerId, title, description, location, contact, url, start, end, createDate, createdBy, lastUpdate, lastUpdateBy
'21', '3', 'test', 'Consultation', '1', '1', '1', '2018-11-30 18:00:00', '2018-11-30 19:00:00', '2018-11-30 16:17:39', 'test', '2018-11-30 16:17:39', 'test'
```

As you can see the above has two valid timestamps at 18:00:00 and at 19:00:00, so the appointment will be at those times in UTC

```
private boolean updateForm(){
    LocalDate localDate = datePicker.getValue();
    LocalTime startTime =  LocalTime.parse(startTimeField.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(), timeDTF);
    LocalTime endTime = LocalTime.parse(endTimeField.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(), timeDTF);

    LocalDateTime startDT = LocalDateTime.of(localDate, startTime);
    LocalDateTime endDT = LocalDateTime.of(localDate, endTime);

    ZonedDateTime startUTC = startDT.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    ZonedDateTime endUTC = endDT.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"));            

Timestamp startsqlts = Timestamp.valueOf(startUTC.toLocalDateTime()); //this value can be inserted into database
    Timestamp endsqlts = Timestamp.valueOf(endUTC.toLocalDateTime()); //this value can be inserted into database        


    System.out.println("Timestamp value start: " + startsqlts.toString() + " end: " + endsqlts.toString());

//OUTPUT OF ABOVE
//"Timestamp value start: 2018-11-30 18:00:00.0 end: 2018-11-30 19:00:00.0"
    try{
            PreparedStatement st = sqlConnection.prepareStatement("UPDATE appointment SET customerId = ?, title = ?, description = ?, start = ?, end = ?, lastUpdate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, lastUpdateBy = ? WHERE appointmentId = ?");

            st.setString(1, Integer.toString(customerTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getId().getValue().intValue()));
            st.setString(2, titleField.getText());
            st.setString(3, typeField.getValue());
            //Inserting timestamps directly
            st.setTimestamp(4, startsqlts);
            st.setTimestamp(5, endsqlts);
            st.setString(6, mainScheduler.currentUser);
            st.setString(7, Integer.toString(appointment.getId().getValue().intValue()));

            if(st.executeUpdate() > 0){
                System.out.println("Updated appointment");

                return true;
            }else{
                System.out.println("Failed to update appointment");
            }

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

As you can see above from the output I put below my print the timestamps are valid, yet after this call exits and I look at my table I have this: (**Nothing else modifies my table in between this call and the time I check**):

```
appointmentId, customerId, title, description, location, contact, url, start, end, createDate, createdBy, lastUpdate, lastUpdateBy
'21', '3', 'test', 'Consultation', '1', '1', '1', '2018-12-01 02:00:00', '2018-12-01 03:00:00', '2018-11-30 16:17:39', 'test', '2018-11-30 16:29:00', 'test'
```

Which shows that the upload is adding 8 hours to an already formatted timestamp.

How is this remedied? It's been the sole problem behind my application not working for almost a week now and I just isolated it so any help is greatly appreciated.

For a reference I am 8 hours behind UTC, so my local time + 8 hours = UTC.

EDIT:
If it's not apparent I'm calling update with no changes so that it's easier to see the change reflected.

Comment: What is the default timezone of your JVM? Your problem is likely one discussed in [Is java.sql.Timestamp timezone specific?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070572/is-java-sql-timestamp-timezone-specific). Consider using `java.time.LocalDateTime` **without** using `java.sql.Timestamp`. That should be supported with `get/setObject` on JDBC 4.2 compliant drivers.

Comment: My default would be PST. Everyone always suggests me to use the opposite of what I'm using at the time and I really would rather not switch again.

Comment: I do appreciate the help though, I'm quite done with dealing with the whole thing so if worst comes to worst I'll be uploading it as a string instead of a timestamp object since that seems to work just fine.

Comment: Are the "start" and "end" columns of the type `TIMESTAMP` in your MySQL table?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel re: "Consider using java.time.LocalDateTime without using java.sql.Timestamp." - That was my thought as well. However, I found that [MySQL Connector/J still has problems dealing with LocalDateTime query parameters](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93444). The saga continues ....