# How to insert timestamp in UTC

Tags: java, jdbc

My partial table definition (MySQL) looks as follows:

```
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ...       | ...      | ..   | ... | ...     | ...            |
| timestamp | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ...       | ...      | ..   | ... | ...     | ...            |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to update the timestamp field using JDBC.  The assumption is that the timestamp is in **UTC**.

In my Java code I am obtaining the timestamp field as follows:

```
Timestamp datetime = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
```

The documentation for the [java.util.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) states that:

> Although the Date class is intended to reflect coordinated universal
> time (UTC), it may not do so exactly, depending on the host
> environment of the Java Virtual Machine.

Unfortunately on my Windows 10 environment (java version "1.8.0_231"), the Date object reflects my local timezone.  As a result the timestamp that gets added to the database is for the local timezone, not UTC.

How can I obtain the timestamp in UTC, so that the correct value is added to the database?

Comment: Be careful with the description of the type. In MySQL `datetime` is a type where it will store the value without timezone information and you need to know which timezone to use to store/retrieve it, while `timestamp` will always stored the value in the database as UTC and you can be flexible with which timezone is use to store or retrieve the value.

Comment: See also [Is java.sql.Timestamp timezone specific?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070572/is-java-sql-timestamp-timezone-specific)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Q) How can I obtain the timestamp in UTC

Do it as follows:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));
Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(zdt.toLocalDateTime());
```

**Notes:**

1. Since you want to work with a timestamp, I recommend you change the field type to `TIMESTAMP`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/should-i-use-the-datetime-or-timestamp-data-type-in-mysql) for more details.
2. Stop using the outdated `java.util` date-time API and switch to [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

Comment: `OffsetDateTime` is more appropriate here than `ZonedDateTime`. And `OffsetDateTime` can be directly sent to the database, so no need for the troubled legacy class `java.sql.Timestamp`.

Comment: Saved my day even after getting time in utc by Instant.now wasn't getting way to put that in SQLQuery

Answer (score 7):

## tl;dr

You have the wrong data type in MySQL, and the wrong class in Java.

- Write to a column of type [`TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) rather than `DATETIME`.
- Use [`java.time.OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) rather than `java.sql.Timestamp`.

Example code snippet.

```
myPreparedStatement
.setObject( 
    … ,                       // Specify which placeholder `?` to fill-in.
    OffsetDateTime            // JDBC 4.2 and later requires a JDBC driver support exchanging `java.time.OffsetDateTime` objects with the database.
    .now( ZoneOffset.UTC )    // Capture the current moment as seen in UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds). 
)
```

## Wrong data type in MySQL

> The assumption is that the timestamp is in UTC

Do you understand that [`DATETIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) in MySQL is *not* in UTC? That type in MySQL has no concept of time zone nor offset-from-UTC.

If you are tracking moments, specific points on the timeline, you have the wrong data type in MySQL. You should be using `TIMESTAMP` to track moments in MySQL.

## Wrong Java classes

You are using *terrible* date-time classes that were bundled with the earliest versions of Java. Those classes were supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes in Java 8 and later, as defined in JSR 310. Never use the `java.sql.Timestamp` class.

To get the current moment in UTC, use `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

Define your column in MySQL as type `TIMESTAMP`.

You *may* be able to write an `Instant` via your JDBC driver. However, JDBC 4.2 requires support for `OffsetDateTime` but oddly omits required support for `Instant`. No matter, we can easily convert.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Write that to the database using your JDBC driver compliant with JDBC 4.2 or later, through a prepared statement.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

## Time zone problem eliminated

If you follow the code seen here you will have no time zone problems.

- None of this code depends on the JVM’s current default time zone.
- None of this code depends on the database server’s current default time zone.

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
- For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: JDBC only defines support for `java.time.OffsetDateTime` on `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` columns. Have you verified if `getObject(.., OffsetDateTime.class)` works in this case?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel As I said three times in the Answer, the database in the Question is using the wrong data type in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can let MySQL to insert a timestamp using this column definition

```
CREATE TABLE SOME_TABLE_NAME (
     SOME_COLUMN_NAME TIMESTAMP default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```