# Does the TIMESTAMP datatype of Oracle store dates adjusted as per the local timezone?

Tags: java, oracle

I have a java application that uses Spring JDBC to store data into Oracle. The data includes timestamps/dates which we use to query certain data in the future.

The date fields are defined like so in the DDL SQL file :

```
JobExecution {
    START_TIME TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL ,
    END_TIME TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL 
...
}
```

Java code to update these fields looks like so :

```
lastJobExecution.setEndTime(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

`new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())` stores current time in UTC format as per documentation below. The documentation of `System.currentTimeMillis()` says that it returns the following :

> the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and
> midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.

The documentation of `Date` says the following :

> Allocates a Date object and initializes it to represent the specified
> number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the
> epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.
>
> Params: date – the milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.
> See Also: System.currentTimeMillis()

However, when I connect to the oracle database using SQL developer, the date seems to be stored as per the local time and not UTC.

Questions :

1. Does Oracle `TIMESTAMP` adjust the date as per the local time? I can't find this explicitly written anywhere in the Oracle documentation.
2. If yes what would be the best way to handle this. One way could be to convert this to UTC every time I read the data from this table. Another way could be to store it in the UTC format itself.

Comment: Reading [this oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1007248) it seems that `TIMESTAMP` stores the time information without further timezone information, i.e. it just stores whatever it is given. To store in the local timezone, we would use `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is java.sql.Timestamp timezone specific?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070572/is-java-sql-timestamp-timezone-specific)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it does partially answer my question. However, the difference is the java code perhaps that is the way I am storing the data into Oracle. I am using spring JDBC to store the and the intermediate steps that convert the date to the TIMESTAMP datatype are not clear to me atleast.

Comment: The best way probably is to switch to using `java.time.LocalDateTime` instead of `java.util.Date`/`java.sql.Timestamp`.

Comment: @Turing85 Seems like thats not the case. I have updated the documentation of Date and System.currentTimeMillis. They generate date in UTC format. So somewhere it seems that the date is converted/adjusted as per the local timezone.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Actually I am working with Spring Batch (which I haven't mentioned in the question as I didn't think it was relevant). The JobExecution class comes from that library and the data types cannot be changed. It uses the Date data type.

Comment: Is - by any chance - the timezone of spring-boot or the server set to `GMT` or `UTC`?

Answer (score 2):

No, the `TIMESTAMP` data type does not store any time zone information.

See [*Datetime Data Types*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/cncpt/tables-and-table-clusters.html#GUID-F5FBE34D-911C-4818-9D25-64B2F1613A9B) documentation.

Oracle provides two timestamp data type supporting time zones:

- `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`

As the name implies it stores the timestamp with time zone information. Time zone can be give as region name (e.g. `Europe/Zurich`) or as UTC offset. Note, you cannot create an index on such column directly. Instead Oracle creates a virtual column of `SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(<your column>)` and index is created on this virtual column. You may need to adapt your queries accordingly.

Often when you work with time zones, then a common approach is to store all times as UTC times and the client converts it to local times. This is exactly provided by second data type:

- `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`

In a `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` all values are stored at `DBTIMEZONE` (which defaults to UTC) but values are **always** displayed in current user session time zone.

Another note, all comparison (e.g. `<, >, =, >=, <=`) of `TIMESTAMP WITH [LOCAL] TIME ZONE` values are performed on according UTC value.