# Convert a sql UTC Timesamp to Instant in Java

Tags: java, sql-server, date, java-11

I am working on a solution which will need to `compare date and time which are stored in a database with the current time in Java`. Stored date and time is in UTC and it is a **java.sql.Timestamp**. I use **java.time.Instant** to compare but I need to convert the stored Timestamp to an Instant. I used **Timestamp.toInstant()** but it is returning the wrong time. Please refer the example below for the code.

> Timestamp timeStamp = 2023-08-08 07:52:09.877 *// This is in UTC.*

> timeStamp.toInstant = 2023-08-08T02:22:09.877Z *// Converted UTC value.*

Tried to find a method that can pass the timezone of the time that we input to the toInstant method but unable to find any.

Anyone aware of a solution to get the same UTC time in to the Instant object?

Comment: Compare `timeStamp.getTime()` and `timeStamp.toInstant().toEpochMilli()`. Are they the same number? If they are, then the result is correct and you are probably formatting the `java.sql.Timestamp` incorrectly.

Comment: ```timeStamp.getTime()``` and ```timeStamp.toInstant().toEpochMilli()``` same. But I am not formatting the ```java.sql.Timestamp``` in any point after getting that from the database.

Comment: You are, otherwise you wouldn't have written `2023-08-08 07:52:09.877`. That string is the result of formatting. Try formatting the `Timestamp` with a [`DateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DateFormat.html) that has its timezone set to UTC.

Comment: In which timezone are you located?

Comment: *Stored date and time is in UTC* Are you *certain* of that? What RDBMS?

Comment: *Timestamp timeStamp = 2023-08-08 07:52:09.877 // This is in UTC.* E.g in MySql, not any longer it isn't. It was *stored* in UTC but was converted to your timezone on retrieval

Comment: I m using MSSQL as my DB and I am storing the time as UTC with the following prepared statement code.

```prepStat.setTimestamp(TimeStamp, Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(UTC));```

Comment: You should probably be trying to do something more like call `setObject` with type `java.time.Instant` but I'm not sure what MSSQL does with its datetimes

Comment: Post your additional details as edits to the Question, not as Comments.

Comment: What is the *exact* data type of the column in your table?

Comment: Keep away from the ole `java.sql.Timestamp` `Calendar` and `TimeZone` classes. They were troublesome and poorly designed and typically gave you issues such as what you are experiencing (and/or other issues too). Best to use `timestamp with time zone` if MS SQL supports it (which I think) and `OffsetDateTime` in Java.

Comment: Assuming you had a `timestamp` without time zone in your database, what happened was that something in your system assumed it was in your local time zone and falsely converted it to a `java.sql.Timestamp` using this assumption. If you cannot change the database data type (which I hope you can), retrieve a `LocalDateTime` from the database and perform your own conversion to UTC so that you control that it is done correctly.

Comment: `prepStat.setObject(n, Instant.now(), java.time.Instant.class); // (where 'n' is 1-based column index` is probably worth trying. Inverse op for select

Comment: @g00se It’s certainly on the right track. Did you try it, though? I didn’t. Asking becuase i suspect that the third argument to [`setObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject(int,java.lang.Object,java.sql.SQLType)) should perhaps be [JDBCType.TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/JDBCType.html#TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE)?

Comment: @OleV.V. unfortunately not as I don't have MSSQL.

Comment: afaics offsets are supported (`datetimeoffset` type) but not timezones

Comment: JDBC does not specify support for `Instant`, so it will not work on all JDBC drivers. JDBC defines support for `java.time.LocalDateTime` for `TIMESTAMP`, and `java.time.OffsetDateTime` for (SQL Standard) `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

Comment: Related: [Is java.sql.Timestamp timezone specific?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070572/is-java-sql-timestamp-timezone-specific)

Answer (score 3):

### `Timestamp#toInstant` is indeed in UTC

> convert the stored Timestamp to an Instant

Calling [`java.sql.Timestamp#toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toInstant()) will indeed give you a date and time as seen with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC. Both classes internally keep a count since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z.

```
Instant instant = myJavaSqlTimestamp.toInstant() ;
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The `Timestamp` class is one of the terribly flawed legacy date-time classes. These were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Never use `Timestamp`, `Calendar`, `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat`, etc. Use only *java.time* classes with JDBC 4.2+.

### With zone/offset

If the column in your [Microsoft SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) database is of the type [`datetimeoffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), then retrieve the matching type in JDBC: [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

Writing:

```
String input = "2023-08-08 07:52:09.877Z" ;  // `Z` on the end indicates an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC. Pronounced "Zulu". 
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input ) ;  // Represents a moment as seen with an offset of zero from UTC.
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;  // Represents a moment as seen with a particular offset from UTC. In this case the offset is zero.
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

### Without zone/offset

I suspect your problem is due to an incorrect data type on your column. You neglected to indicate the data type, so I can only guess. But I guess the type is the legacy Microsoft SQL Server type [`datetime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) or its modern replacement [`datetime2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Both of those `datetime`/`datetime2` types represent a date with time-of-day but lack the context of a time zone or an offset-from-UTC. Without that context, such a value does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a specific point on the timeline. So **comparing to a value in UTC is nonsensical**.

The matching JDBC type for those `datetime`/`datetime2` types is `LocalDateTime` — a class representing a date with time-of-day but without zone/offset.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

Writing:

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ldt ) ;
```

**Do *not* use those `datetime`/`datetime2` types nor `LocalDateTime`** if you are tracking a moment, a specific point on the timeline. That would be like storing an amount of money without noting the currency.

If you did indeed use those `datetime`/`datetime2` types in an attempt to store a moment, then you now have a mess on your hands. You will need to use a [`datetimeoffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) instead. To migrate data, you can assign an offset if you know *for certain* the intended offset of the stored values, but you will of course ultimately be guessing since you cannot know the context of every row’s insertion/update.