# Timestamp's datetime string is shown in local timezone instead of UTC on select

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

My entity has a `java.sql.Timestamp` field:

```
@Column(name = "expires_at")
private Timestamp expiresAt;
```

The table also has a default column `updated_at`, which is dynamically set on insertions/updates (i.e it is not set through JPA):

```
  updated_at       DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

I set `expiresAt` in the persisted entity this way:

```
long currTimestamp = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochSecond(currTimestamp), ZoneId.of("UTC"));
Timestamp expiresAt = Timestamp.valueOf(ldt);

myEntity.setExpiresAt(expiresAt);
```

I am located in PDT timezone. I run Spring Boot app locally, and it uses MySQL container in my Docker Desktop.
This query shows UTC time, which means that MySQL container's timezone is UTC:

```
select now();
```

But when I persist my entity into the table, and do `select`, the datetime string of `expires_at` column shows PDT time. And `updated_at` column shows UTC time.

Interestingly, the records persisted from my AWS ECS Spring Boot app into AWS RDS MySQL instance, show UTC for both `expires_at` and `updated_at`.

When I update local JDBC string (for connecting to Docker Desktop container) to `mysql://localhost:3306/mydbname?connectionTimeZone=UTC`, it shows UTC for both.

Can anyone explain why this happens? And why in AWS RDS they are both shown in UTC even though I am not using `connectionTimeZone` flag there

Comment: Related: [Is java.sql.Timestamp timezone specific?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070572/is-java-sql-timestamp-timezone-specific). Scratch that, on further reading, it is a duplicate.

Comment: feel sorry for you that it is considered as duplicated. IMO it is just related but not exactly duplicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`updated_at` is simple to understand. Since its value is defined by MySQL , it is always equal to the MySQL timezone which is UTC in both of your local MySQL and AWS RDS.

`expires_at` is trickier as its value is managed by the JDBC driver which also has its timezone setting. When using

```java
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(index, timestamp)
```

which hibernate is default to use to configure which value of the time will be stored to DB , the JDBC driver will convert it based on its timezone setting which can be defined explicitly by `connectionTimeZone` in the JDBC connection URL. Otherwise , it will default to use JVM timezone. So think that your spring-boot app running in AWS is configured as UTC timezone now.

Different situations for `expires_at` can be explained as follows :

- Run in local + no `connectionTimeZone` configured ➜  JDBC driver default to JVM timezone (i.e PDT) ➜  stores in PDT time
- Run in local + `connectionTimeZone=UTC` ➜   JDBC driver convert it to UTC  ➜  stores in UTC time
- Run in AWS + no `connectionTimeZone` configured ➜  JDBC driver default to JVM timezone (i.e UTC) ➜  stores in UTC time

As MySQL `DATETIME` will not store any timezone information , it is up to the client application that fetch its value to define the timezone. If you do not want to changes its data type , recommend you to at least align your JVM and DB to be in the same timezone setting to prevent some weird problem. I guess now in your local setup you will experience a time shift problem for `updated_at` when hibernate  fetches its value because it will treat it as a PDT time but actually it is a UTC time.

Comment: thanks, you're right, `updated_at` would have a time shift. we don't fetch it through hibernate at the moment, it's only used for housekeeping the table.

Comment: so, you mean that JVM in spring boot's ECS container on AWS has timezone configured as UTC, that's why it stores `expires_at` in UTC without `connectionTimeZone`, is that right?

Comment: yes ............

Answer (score 2):

You’ve got a mess there.

First of all, stop using `java.sql.Timestamp`. That terribly flawed legacy class was years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. JDBC 4.2+ supports *java.time*. Jakarta Persistence (JPA) and Hibernate have both been updated to support *java.time*.

Never use `LocalDateTime` when handling moments, specific points on the timeline. That type lacks the context of a time zone or offset.

Write your code in such a way so that your MySQL container's timezone is irrelevant.

Your database column must be of a type akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. In MySQL, tha means the type `TIMESTAMP`. **You have used the wrong type** on your column, `DATETIME`. Read the documentation to learn how that type lacks the context of a time zone or offset. That `DATETIME` type stores only a date with a time of day, so it is inherently ambiguous.

JDBC maps `OffsetDateTime` class to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( Offset.UTC ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( "updated_at" , odt ) ;
```

Retrieval:

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( "updated_at" , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

All this has been covered many times before on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

Comment: _"All this has been covered many times before on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more."_ may be close as duplicate then?

Comment: I recommend using this answer that uses the modern API.